# How to get Event Count from Triggered Actions in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm trying to get Goal Count for the triggered events on my website.. I've setup two events (click) in javascript, and 2 corresponding Goals in the Google Analytics.

My Analytics Goals are:

1. Download Catalog (Zone 1)
2. Download Catalog (Zone 2)

Here's a screenshot of how the first Goal is setup...

[image]

And in my javascript file, I've setup the following code to be triggered on click of the links. This javascript file has been placed in the `<head>` of the document.

```
/* Google Analytics GOAL Actions */

 $(document).ready(function(){
    var page_meta = $('meta[name=topic]').attr("content");
    if(page_meta.length > 25) page_meta = page_meta.substring(0,25) + '..';
    var label_page; 

    ///////// GOAL 1: EVENT :: PDF Download
    $('a.g-btn.type_primary').on('click', function() {
    label_page = 'Page:: ' + page_meta;
    console.log('Download_PDF');
     ga('send', 'event', 'Domestic', 'DownloadPDF', label_page, 1);
    }); ///////// END GOAL 1
 }); //Document Ready() ///
/* END Google Analytics GOAL Actions */
```

I've created custom labels in the above code, cause I thought labels would be visible in the Goals Overview. This is my first attempt at generating Goals so I have no knowledge in what I'm doing wrong...!

That's mostly all..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured this out... I had to create a custom report with the following setup...

[image: Event Users Count with Action, Category, Label and Page Title in Report]

Comment: That's the event count. Since an event can be triggered multiple times per session but a goal will be counted only once per session the goal count and the event count are not the same (just saying, because your question was about goal counts).

Comment: Yes it was! Well, I was expecting the event data to be presented automatically in the default Analytics Dashboard... and since that wasn't happening, so I asked here... just recently learned I should create custom report for the triggered event that was being recorded as a Goal in the settings...

Comment: Well, they might have the same value but goal count and event count are _technically_ not the same. It might of course be that your users trigger the event only once per session, but that is coincidence, not a feature of analytics.

Comment: Well, my event trigger is mostly on `click` of links and buttons, so it's not video playtime based where the value could increase with duration of the video being played... So I didn't need Goal count.. I guess I should change the Question Title to Event Counts instead of Goal Counts, so that other people seeking the same answer could find this page easily... Or is the question title valid?